# Can I run a 50 amp circuit for a hot tub from a 60 amp sub panel

Tags: wiring

I recently had a pool installed with a commercial water slide. My sub panel is a 60 amp panel fed from a 200 amp main panel 70 feet away with 4 awg wire. The main and sub panels both have 60 amp breakers. I have 2 pumps powered off of this panel. Both are wired to separate 20 amp 240v circuits. I have 2 120v outlets on separate 20 amp circuits. 1 feeds an outlet for a natural gas pool heater and the other is an unused convenience outlet. The pumps are a 1 hp for the pool and a 3 hp for the slide. I want to add a hot tub next year. Is the sub panel and wiring sufficient to run a 50 amp circuit for the hot tub?

Comment: What's the nameplate amperage rating of the hot tub you're looking at?

Comment: Also, what's the nameplate rating of the pumps?

Comment: I haven't decided on a particular tub yet. Still looking at options. The pumps show 10 amps on one and 11.4 on the other. Is it safe to assume that I should be looking for something that draws 30 amps or less?  Also I forgot to mention the sub panel is fed with 4 awg copper so if needed I could increase the breaker size without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have some of the electrical data for the hot tub. If it's going to be a 5.5KW heater and a 3 HP pump and with everything running , you'd be ok.